# Prevent hiddenType modification

Tags: symfony

I create an ecommerce site, I store the total of the command in a hiddenType. On my delivery page, I do like this:

```
{% set total = 0 %}
{% for produit in produits %}

{% set total = total +(produit.price * panier[produit.id]) %}

{% endfor %}

{{ form_row(form.total, {'value' : total }) }}
```

The problem is that the user can change the amount using the Inspector :
[hiddenType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwVVY.jpg)

There is no way to hide the hiddenType in the inspector?

Comment: If you need to hide confidential data just don't store it into an hidden form field. 
Call your own service who will temporary store this data in database or textFile in your server or in user Session.It is better than hidding in form  hidden field.

Comment: This can help. It's an ecommerce solution built on top of symfony: http://sylius.org/

Comment: Thank you but this is for a student project, I do not want to use sylius, there is no easier way?